# Restrictions of XMLHttpRequest's getResponseHeader()?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I've noticed that the results of and `XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader()` don't always match the real headers returned (if the request is made in a regular manner).

For example, assume I'm making an `xhr` request for `https://foo.example.com/api/resource/100`. In Chrome's developer console, under 'Network', I can see the response being made -- I can also see all of the response headers (say, 10). However (copy-pasted console):

```
> response
  XMLHttpRequest
> response.getAllResponseHeaders();
  "content-type: text/html
  "
```

Are there any restrictions on what headers are available? Is this dependent on the response type? I remember getting a complete set of headers for 404s but just this one for 400s.

What gives?

Comment: If I make a request to `http://stackoverflow.com/` on this page, I am able to get all headers back. I'm not sure how to reproduce.

Comment: I'm aware of the vagueness -- trying to narrow down to a suitable case. The original request made is  cross-origin request, with Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Excuse the rushed feeling of the question, will elaborate soon: I didn't have time to investigate this further at the moment. I was hoping this was some sort of a known restriction that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The current state of standardizing the [XMLHttpRequest API](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) does only restrict the access to the *Set-Cookie* and *Set-Cookie2* header fields:

> ***client*.getAllResponseHeaders()**
>
> Returns all headers from the response, with the exception of those whose field name is `Set-Cookie` or `Set-Cookie2`.

Any other header field should be returned.

But as you’re doing a cross-origin request, the browser needs to implement [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) as the original XMLHttpRequest does only allow same-origin requests:

> The XMLHttpRequest Level 2 specification enhances the XMLHttpRequest object with new features, such as cross-origin requests […]

There you can read that the “[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) filters the headers that filters the headers that are exposed by [getResponseHeader()](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-getallresponseheaders-method) for non [same-origin](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/origin-0.html#same-origin) requests.”. And that specification forbids access to any response header field other except the [simple response header fields](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-response-header) (i.e. *Cache-Control*, *Content-Language*, *Content-Type*, *Expires*, *Last-Modified*, and *Pragma*):

> User agents must filter out all response headers other than those that are a simple response header […]
>
> E.g. the `getResponseHeader()` method of XMLHttpRequest will therefore not expose any header not indicated above.

Comment: Right, thanks. There are still some mysteries left, though.. I've set a proper `Access-Control-Expose-Headers:` -- only to find out it works only in Gecko, not WebKit. WebKit happily "Refused to get unsafe header (..)", Gecko sees no problem. Second issue: `getAllResponseHeaders()` lies. I can `getResponseHeader()` headers that the former doesn't list as available.

Comment: @maligree: [WebKit doesn’t support the *Access-Control-Expose-Headers* yet.](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41210) But what about the other issue? What browser does that?

Comment: Yes, I've stumbled upon that bugzilla issue -- but seeing the date it was opened, I took it with a grain of salt . *And* as to the second issue, I'm seeing this in Firefox 6. `getAllResponseHeaders()` returns `""`, while a `getResponseHeader('content-length')` or `getResponseHeader('www-authenticate')` (which is one of the headers I'm setting and `Access-Control-Expose-Header`'ing) returns the proper header value. I'd rather not expose the URI used at this time, but if it helps, I can devise an isolated test case later.

Comment: @maligree you meant `null` right ? cf https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=608735

Answer (score 3):

It's the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and the way it allows to prevent which headers are exposed to the browser. [Docs at mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control).