# AJAX get custom response headers with CORS

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, cors

My server sends custom headers along with the response. I get the response data alright, but I can't access the custom headers with jQuery's `getAllResponseHeaders()` or AngularJS `$http` service. All I get is `content-type`. When I inspect the request response with DevTools or fiddler, I can see all the custom headers being sent by the server, but I can't get them from xhr. Is there any way to access all the headers?

Answer (score 7):

OK I got this working after adding allowed headers in my server config `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

Comment: Yes, any cross-origin response headers which are not considered ["simple"](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-response-header) must be referenced in a Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header in order for them to be accessible via XHR.