# How to get value in Response header Angular2

Tags: http, angular

i want to get session token in response header(Set-Cookie).how can i access values in Response header ?

```
var headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            console.log('url',this.loginUrl)
            this.http.post(this.loginUrl,
                JSON.stringify({ "username": value.username, "password": value.password }),
                { headers: headers })
                .map((res: Response) => 
                    res.json())
                .subscribe((res) => {
                    console.log("res", res);
                    this.loading.hide();
                    if (res.message_code == "SUCCESS") {
                        this.nav.setRoot(HomePage, {
                            username: value.username,
                        });
                    } else {
                        let alert =  Alert.create({
                            title: "Sign In Error !",
                            subTitle: 'Please Check Username or Password.',
                            buttons: ['Ok']
                        });
                        this.nav.present(alert);
                    }
                }, err => {
                    this.loading.hide();
                    console.log('error', err);

                });
```

this is my header response

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that you map your response to its json content. Headers can be reached from the response itself. So you need to remove the `map` operator:

```
this.http.post(this.loginUrl,
       JSON.stringify({ "username": value.username, "password": value.password }),
       { headers: headers })
        /*.map((res: Response) =>  // <--------------
                res.json())*/
       .subscribe((res) => {
         var payload = res.json();
         var headers = res.headers;

         var setCookieHeader = headers.get('Set-Cookie')
         (...)
       });
```

Be careful with CORS with accessing the response headers. See this question:

- [angular2/http get location header of 201 response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280565/angular2-http-get-location-header-of-201-response/36281935#36281935)

Comment: thanks for quick response.but  `setCookieHeader ` give me a `null` value

Comment: You're welcome! What is the content of the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` of the preflighted options  request?

Comment: in server side `origin, content-type, accept` from my app post request types are `x-requested-with`

Comment: `headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");`

Comment: hi any help about this question

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=3A8DA9A7DE3A41F980CC6C18A569BBCA; Path=/CRM_WEBSERVICE/; HttpOnly
JSESSIONID: JSESSIONID=3A8DA9A7DE3A41F980CC6C18A569BBCA
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 08:51:21 GMT`

Comment: but in here i has `Set-Cookie` value

Comment: Yes, but XHR (XMLHttpRequest) will skip headers that aren't specified in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header in the context of cross domain requests (CORS) ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108375/discussion-between-kosala-and-thierry-templier).

Comment: can you tell me how can i do that in java spring

Comment: I don't know how your server application is implemented but I think that you could use the `allowedHeaders` method on the `CorsRegistry` class. This link could help you: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html.

Comment: .i modified my function with `headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` the i got a `null` as value

Comment: Yes but you have a preflighted request. So I guess that you need to do that on the implicite options method. That's why I think you need to do something with the spring cors support. Perhaps something can be done with annotations...

Answer (score 6):

One way to solve that issue is to specify from your backend which one of the pairs {key: value} of your headers you want to expose.

Using a java backend, you can add the following lines:

```java
public void methodJava(HttpServletResponse response){
...
response.addHeader("access-control-expose-headers", "Set-Cookie");
}
```

And now you can access this cookie element with your angular this way

```js
service(){
...
return this.http
    .get(<your url here for your backend>)
    .map(res => console.log("cookie: " + res.headers.get("Set-Cookie") )
}
```

More explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

Answer (score 4):

`.map((res: Response) => {
    localStorage.setItem('setCookie', res.headers._headers.get("Set-Cookie")[0]);
    res.json()
})`

or you can take reference from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Headers-class.html

Comment: explain what's related in your answer not just place the link.

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5237#issuecomment-239174349)

You need to set permission at producer side  to access headers as -

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Custom-header");
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Custom-header");
```

And in angular you can do this -

```
this._http.get(url, options).toPromise()
            .then(res => {
                var data = res.headers.get('X-Custom-header');
                console.log(data);
                return res;
            })
```

Check it out.

Comment: Please accept this as correct answer or upvote if it solved your problem, so that other users can find it helpful

Comment: But i get undefine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to expose the headers on the server-side. Some headers are allowed to access from the client, like content-type, but not all. For more details have a look at paragraph: 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers (optional)' in  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 1):

This stumped me for an hour. Although Chrome debugger shows the 'Location' header I was unable to read it in angular@4.3.3 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.0

It turns out it was a CORS issue. The fix was a one liner in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
    builder.WithOrigins("https://mywebsite")
        .WithExposedHeaders("Location")  // <--------- ADD THIS LINE
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod());
```

And now I can read the header in angular:

```
this.authHttp.post('https://someapi/something', {name: 'testing'})
    .map((response: Response) => {
        // The following line now works:
        const url = response.headers.get('Location');
    });
```

I'm not sure how Chrome can see it but angular couldn't - it's obviously still part of the actual web api response.

Comment: [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "Token")] is another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with Angular 4.2.+;

**Service**

```
getProfile(data) {
   return this.httpClient
      .request(new HttpRequest("POST", this.url, {}));
}
```

**Component**

```
this.userService.getProfile().subscribe(
  (response: any) => {
    if (response.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
      // response.headers is here
    }
  },
  (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    this.showMessage("error", "An error occurred");
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is easy, just use the **Location** from **url** inside **map** function

```
.map((data: Response) => { response.url })
```