# Angular2 http token

Tags: http, angular, ionic2, token

How to get the token instead of the json file. 
The token is send by the Server in the Header from an http get request.

```
this.http.get('http://192.168.0.1:8080/DataBaseAccess/Connection', options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});


Response Headers (viewed in Chrome):

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:2
Date:Thu, 02 Feb 2017 11:18:30 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
token:By7fCLT7PdCKtCmlCQad8LM1fwYIvhXf56anTrgZtpQ8MMWmGQ5xok6tjU7g7ZspJgUiUzIxJoKyl5eh0Rc2IBvkyZ1vN9CWpjdB
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423388/how-to-get-value-in-response-header-angular2

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.