# No Authorization header found when being sent via Angular 4 interceptor - Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm building an app with *login*.

The user can *login* and a *token* is returned to the front end.

The problem is occurring when, I'm sending the token back to the server to be verified.

I'm using a `HttpInterceptor` to send the *Authorization* header to the server.

When I log in the console:

```
  console.log(cloned.headers.get("Authorization"))
```

The header is displayed fine, however, when logged in the express middleware

```
console.log(req.headers.authorization);
```

I get `undefined`

Also below are the request headers from the network tab, as you can see, no Authorization

[image]

*Interceptor*:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const id_token = localStorage.getItem("id_token");

    if (id_token) {
      const cloned = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + id_token)
      });
      // console.log(cloned)
      console.log(cloned.headers.get("Authorization"))
      return next.handle(cloned);
    }
    else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

*express*:

```
router.use('/edit', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.headers.authorization);
  const checkIfAuthenticated = expressJwt({
    secret: RSA_PUBLIC_KEY
  });

  if (checkIfAuthenticated) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      title: 'Not Authorised',
      error: 'You are not authorised'
    });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The Authorization-header is hidden by default. 
In your backend you need to expose the header:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
```

Please see this thread as a reference:

[Angular 2: Get Authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314069/angular-2-get-authorization-header)

@Update: 
Sorry, misunderstood your question.
Please recheck your second console.log(). You're logging:

```
console.log(req.headers.authorization);
```

Shouldn't that be

```
console.log(req.headers.get("Authorization"));
```

instead?

Comment: thanks, tried but didn't work, isn't that for when you want the front end to read headers returned? My problem is not getting header server side

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. Please check my update in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some comments on how to implement interceptors that might help your case:

**1) Interceptors require angular version 4.3 || >**

**2) Remember to provide the interceptor in our main app.module:**

```
/** Interceptors */
import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http'; <-- notice the common in @angular/common/http 
import {TokenInterceptor} from './path/to/TokenInterceptor ';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**3) In your service that reaches the endpoint, make sure to add the new http client:**

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'; <-- Super important to include new HttpClient from @angular/common/http instead of old http from @angular/http...

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { }
// your GET POST and other requests made with http will now have the desired header...
```

**4) Also, edit your interceptor code and add `setHeaders` :**

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const id_token = localStorage.getItem("id_token");

    if (id_token) {
       req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
             Authorization: `Bearer ${id_token}`
          }
       });
       return next.handle(req);
    }
```

If you already did follow this steps but your header doesnt appear, paste your service and module code

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem with angular 5 and laravel 5 backend with tymon/jwt laravel package to handle token authentication.

The problem in my case is from backend. In my api route I use:
Route::any(...)

When I changed the any to the right http verb (get, post...) The problem go away:
Route::get(...)

When I inspect the network panel in chrome, the request to backend was sent twice, first one with no token and the other with token