# Read headers in Angular 2

Tags: angular, authentication

I have a requirement to integrate Angular 2 application with a Identity mangagement system. When user is successfully authenticated, few information will be sent in http headers to Angular 2 application. Could you please share some idea on how to read headers values in Angular 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423388/how-to-get-value-in-response-header-angular2

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. However its a different scenario, (i.e. headers are posted to Angular 2 app by an external system and we need to read it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as mentioned in many websites we really can't read http headers at the client side (using javascript) if the call is not initiated by itself. If client side application initiates a http request then it is possible to set headers in the request and read headers from the response. So that answers it all, although there are few workarounds (that I read as part of this investigation) such as using workerservice etc. I have come to the conclusion to change our design. (i.e. calling identity management system to request for specific detail instead of trying to read from http headers.)