# How to get the value of Location Header Response in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, httpclient

I am trying to get the value of Header Response [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GPHO.png)"Location" after a post 201 method, I want to get that result and send it as a variable to another api post

```
public saveNote(note: any): Observable\<any\> {
return this.http.post\<any\>(
this.apiURL + '/contract/api/notes/' + Location,
JSON.stringify(note),
this.httpOptions,
)
.pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

How can I do it? I'm already lost
thanks for your help

In Contractadd.ts

```
return this.restApi.post(this.contract, body, options)
        .flatMap((res:Response) => {
          var location = res.headers.get('Location');
          return this._http.get(location);
        }).map((res:Response) => res.json()))
        .catch(this.handleError)
```

Get errors in code TS

In service.ts

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:location
```

Comment: I think this thread might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280565/angular2-http-get-location-header-of-201-response

Comment: I believe it's a CORS problem and the accepted answer in the above mentioned URL adresses it.

Comment: Are you passing the observe: "response" in the httpOptions?