# Angular 2/Cordova - XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('Content-Length') - Avoid "Refused to get unsafe header 'Content-Length'" in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular

I am developing an Hybrid mobile application (Android/Ios) with Cordova / Angular 2 / Ionic 2. To debug quickly, I run my application in Chrome.

I use a lot of XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('HEAD', imgSrc, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        let responseContentLength = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
```

This works great on mobile or emulator. But when I debug in Chrome, I get the following error:

> Refused to get unsafe header "Content-Length"

Is there a way to allow access (only get) to 'Content-Length' header in Chrome?

**Updated** (thanks to [Destrif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5037341/destrif)):
There is a good explanation of what is going on here [Restrictions of XMLHttpRequest's getResponseHeader()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462968/restrictions-of-xmlhttprequests-getresponseheader)
I m doing a cross-origin request (i have a plugin in chrome that's allow CORS), so the browser implement XMLHttpRequest Level 2 specification. This specification forbids access to 'Content-Length' header (and others headers).

When I use the emulator RIPPLE, I do not encounter the error. I know RIPPLE uses a proxy. A proxy for development would solve the problem? How does Ripple?

The goal is to run the app in Chrome without encountering the error.

Comment: I m getting Content-Length (not setting).

Comment: Maybe this will help so:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462968/restrictions-of-xmlhttprequests-getresponseheader

Comment: And to to make it work, you will need CORS(Access-Control-Expose-Headers) example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource
Up vote if you liked it

Comment: With Ripple, i don t have the error message. If i use proxy in Chrome, can i avoid this message?

Comment: Destrif thanks a lot for your answer. This explains very well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462968/restrictions-of-xmlhttprequests-getresponseheader. I can't upvote (i don't have right)

Comment: Günter, could you please reopen this thread? it s not a duplicate. And it s not a "set".

Comment: no chance to reopen?

Comment: Didn't you answer your question?, why do you want to reopen?