# Cross domain calls with webkitdotnet

Tags: c#, javascript, windows, security, webkit

I am trying to use ajax to read and parse results from a website within the webkitbrowser.

There's no obvious solution for disabling web security in webkitdotnet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712937/cors-xhr-getrequestheaders)

Comment: That post is unresolved and doesn't deal with webkitdotnet, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This library is more evolved and although it doesn't have this functionality you can use a c# callback to perform a cross-domain post-request http://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/