# Does Google Compute Engine support HTTP OPTIONS request?

Tags: nginx, cross-domain, google-compute-engine

I have a GCE instance with CentOS6, I installed Nginx and PHP to serve http request, but unfortunately when I send OPTIONS request to GCE instance, it just fails without response, of course it works well on other http request such as GET, PUT....

One thing that confuses me is that when I send LOCK/MOVE/UNLOCK http request to the server, it gives me:

```
HTTP/1.0 501 Unsupported method ('LOCK')
Server: BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.7.5
Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 09:06:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
```

but when I send OPTIONS/CONNECT/TRACE requests it just fails and no response returned.

Any ideas about this? 
Thanks in advance.

By the way I have configured Nginx to support Cross-origin request following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/227939)

Answer (score 1):

Compute Engine doesn't do deep inspection based filtering of HTTP traffic to instances.

Is it possible that your HTTP server doesn't support those HTTP methods, but fails without a response?  The [docs for BaseHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler) suggest that *all* methods have to be implemented by subclassing the handler. So if this is Python BaseHTTP server based code, the response to different HTTP methods will depend on the particular implementation of the code.